# Angular 4 PipeTransform not applied

Tags: angular

My custom pipe to shorten a string isn't working. I have included it in my app.module declarations and imported it in my component. The code is below.

```ts
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
/*
  Takes a string and replaces it with a shortend version based on the length you give it if its greater than 14 char for Example
  someString = "hey whats up my name is Bob and im from Bob town"
  {{value | shortString : length of new string}}
  {{someString | shortString: 10}}
*/
@Pipe({name: 'shortString'})
export class shortString implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, length: number): string {
    console.log('expected new string '+value.slice(0,length)+'...');
    return (value.length()>14)?value.slice(0,length)+'...': value;
  }
}`
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is it generating an error? Or just not shorting the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First in your Pipe

```ts
@Pipe({name: 'shortString'})
export class shortString implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, length: number): string {
    return (value.length()>14)?value.slice(0,length)+'...': value; // remove the length() it will be value.length
  }
}
```

Working plunker of the same

https://plnkr.co/edit/Xz528J1sCi7GlDeWELph?p=preview

Comment: This worked I just had to remove change the .length() to .length.... thanks! Was thinking in c++ lol

Answer (score 4):

Your pipe itself looks fine, but in order to use it, you have to import it into your module, and declare and export it so it's available in your component.

```ts
import { shortString } from './shortString.pipe';
    
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        shortString
    ],
    exports: [
        shortString
    ],
    providers: [
    ]

})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Add this to whichever module is appropriate for your setup, I put all my pipes in a SharedModule, so that's why this is exporting SharedModule, but you may have this in MainModule or something else.